# Swagger not showing API Models and not ignoring default response codes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

As described in the title - **Swagger is not showing API Models and not ignoring default response codes**

I have uploaded the source code to - https://bitbucket.org/vambits/inactiveaccounts/src/master/
`git clone https://bitbucket.org/vambits/inactiveaccounts.git`

1. I am not sure why the API Model objects: `SimpleRequest` and `SimpleResponse` are not showing up in the Swagger UI.
   [image]
   As you can see there are no "Models" at the End.
2. In the code, i have set `.build()).useDefaultResponseMessages(false)` but still the default response codes are getting shown. How to fix this??
   [image]

Note: The functionality of this application is irrelevant.

Swagger Docket Configuration is as below -

```
@Bean
    public Docket swaggerApi()
    {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).protocols(Sets.newHashSet("http", "https"))
                /*
                 * Make sure swagger doesn't auto-generate error responses that we won't be using (e.g. 401, 403)
                 */
                /*
                 * Since SpringFox doesn't support the @SwaggerDefinition, specify that metadata here
                 */
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder().title("InactiveAccountsApplication Pricing").version("1")
                        .contact(new Contact("InactiveAccountsApplication Services", null, "abc-services@xyz.com"))
                        .description(
                                "InactiveAccountsApplication returns the inactive accounts list")
                        .build())
                        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)

                .select()
                
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(InactiveAccountsApplication.class.getPackage().getName()))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use springdoc instead of the springfox libraries, because they are pretty outdated.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

[Here](https://springdoc.org/) you can find the documentation including a migration guide

The models should be included out of the box then.

Regarding your second question:

The response codes shown in your screenshot aren't the default response messages. They are the responses that you described in your controller, so I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: thanks for pointing out what i missed on the second part ( i did not realized i changed it later).

Comment: on the first part - I don't have the flexibility to change from `springfox`. It's used organization wise and I should go with only. Any suggestions on how it fix it while using `springfox`

Comment: seem on first part, i am missing something simple but difficult to spot

Comment: I'm not sure if OpenAPI v2 had the separate section for models because in your example the models are already inside the request.